# Print text of line in two different lines

Tags: sed

My input is as

```
Type combinational  function (A B)
```

Want output to be

```
Type combinational 
function (A B)
```

I used code

```
sed "/'^Type '/a 'function '" input
```

But using this I am getting function word in next line after Type. Where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With shown samples could you please try following.

```
sed 's/\([^ ]* [^ ]*\) \(function.*\)/\1\n\2/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** using back reference capability of `sed`, where I am creating 2 captured groups, 1st group stores values till the 2nd spaces comes into it. 2nd back reference stores values after 2nd space occurs. Then while performing substitution, using `\1` to get values inside 1st back reference and using `\2` 2nd backreference for getting 2nd stored value, Putting `\n` to get a new line between matched values as per question.

Comment: This is not working for input as```Type sequential  function   IQ ;``` why?? Are both inputs not in same format.

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY, its working fine for me(I rechecked again now). Check if you have Control M characters in your Input_file. Do a `cat -v Input_file` and let me know if you see ^M chars? Because this is working fine for me.

Comment: it also worked for me when input was ```Type combinational   function (A B)``` but did not worked for input ```Type sequential function IQ ;```

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY, could you please check my edited answer and let me know then?

Comment: I problem is resolved. There was slight change in input , small modification is done. And its working for another input also. Thanks